# Insert into database with unique/primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a simple form to insert posts to my MySQL database, I want each post to have an unique ID but don't know the proper way to do it.

I already created a column named "PID" and set it as a primary key however I don't know how to make each INSERT generate the PID. The only way I can think of is to make PHP look for the higher PID and add +1 to it. Is there an easier way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage your MySQL database with a software like e.g. phpMyAdmin then you can set the "auto_increment" flag on this column.

Else you have to set it manually as described in [this manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set PID to be an Identity field

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
 CREATE TABLE posts(
 PID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 someotherfield CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 ...etc...,
 PRIMARY KEY (PID)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the field 'auto_increment'. That way, MySQL creates a unique id for each record. You can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

Make the PID column auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

Set that PID field to AUTO_INCREMENT. In PHPMyAdmin there's a INDEX field you can set to AI, if I remember correctly.

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use auto_increment on the field.

E.g. pid int primary key auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on `Id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Make the field auto_increment in your mysql table.